# How to pass function of one class as argument of another function of another class

Tags: c++

I have created a class `Base` which has a function `addSuccessor()` that takes address of function as argument and stores it in successor. How do I pass a function of another object in `addSuccessor()`.
Here is my program. I think my `main()` has some mistake.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
class Base{
public:
    void (*successor)()=NULL;
    void addSuccessor ( void (*f)() )
    {
        successor=f;
    }
    void start()
    {
        cout<<"In Class"<<endl;
        if(!successor==NULL)
            successor();
        else
            cout<<"No Successor"<<endl;
    }
};
class Second{
    public:
    void foo()
    {
        cout<<"Successor";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base obj;
    Second obj2;

    obj.addSuccessor(&obj2.foo());
    obj.start();

}
```

Comment: `foo()` is not a function. It is a non-static class method. You cannot convert non-static class methods directly to function pointers in C++. C++ does not work this way. You need to understand that, and the reason for that; and for this [you need a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Since it's 2020 why not use [C++ lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of function pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a complement to the discussion above (based on @L.F.'s answer):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class Base {
    std::function<int(int)> successor;
public:
    template <typename F>
    void add_successor(F&& f)
    {
        successor = std::forward<F>(f);
    }
    void start()
    {
        if (successor) {
            auto z = std::invoke(successor, 100);
            std::cout << "Output = " << z << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "No Successor\n";
        }
    }
};

class Second {
public:
    int foo(int x)
    {
        auto y = x + x;
        std::cout << "Successor\n";
        return y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Base obj;
    Second obj2;

    obj.add_successor([&](int x)->int { return obj2.foo(x); });
    obj.start();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Function pointers are very limited.  Use a [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) (defined in header [`<functional>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional)) instead, which can store any invocable object in a type-erased manner, and provide a template member function to set the functor in which [perfect forwarding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) is used to forward the provided functor to `successor`: ([`std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) is defined in header [`<utility>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/utility))

```
class Base {
    std::function<void()> successor;
public:
    template <typename F>
    void add_successor(F&& f)
    {
        successor = std::forward<F>(f);
    }
    void start()
    {
        if (successor) {
            successor();
        } else {
            std::cout << "No Successor\n";
        }
    }
};
```

Then, you can pass a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) to `add_successor`:

```
obj.add_successor([&]{ obj2.foo(); });
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iEJCrBT4kuT7C9Rn))

Comment: You can also use `std::invoke`. 
```if (successor) {
            std::invoke(successor);
        } else {
            std::cout << "No Successor\n";
        }```

Comment: @SoumyaKanti [`std::function::operator()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator()) internally uses `INVOKE` to invoke the stored function object, so we can enjoy the intuitive syntax :)

Comment: What if the signature of `foo` member function in class `Second` is `int foo(int)`?

Comment: @SoumyaKanti You can provide the argument in the lambda expression.

Comment: Actually, successor's signature is known and static, so isn't it better to remove template ?

Comment: @arnes How will you specify the type of the lambda in the class then?

Comment: Exactly.Here `F` is the type of the lambda.

Comment: What's wrong with `void add_successor(const std::function<int(int)>& f)` ?

Comment: @arnes Umm ... well, you have to construct `std::function` twice then, which is expensive. I am trying to avoid type erasure unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: I am not sure that it is constructed twice but at least we could add something like `static_assert( std::is_invocable<F>::value , "F's signature should be 'void(*)()'" );` for friendlier error message.

Comment: @arnes Yeah, or we can do SFINAE.  Or we can wait for C++20; `template <std::invocable F>` looks better.